# vb .net, passing enum value as function parameter

Tags: vb.net

This compiles without error but when I run this code section some strange error appears:

FatalExecutionEngineError was detected
Message: The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at 0x792062fb, on thread 0xd7c. The error code is 0xc0000005. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.

I try something like follows:

```
    Public Enum PipePolicyType
        SHORT_PACKET_TERMINATE = 1
        AUTO_CLEAR_STALL = 2
        PIPE_TRANSFER_TIMEOUT = 3
        IGNORE_SHORT_PACKETS = 4
        ALLOW_PARTIAL_READS = 5
        AUTO_FLUSH = 6
        RAW_IO = 7
        RESET_PIPE_ON_RESUME = 9
    End Enum

...
...

        Dim a As UInt32 = 3000

        SetPolicy(1, PIPE_TRANSFER_TIMEOUT, a)

...
...
Public Sub SetPolicy(ByVal ep As Integer, ByVal PolicyType As PipePolicyType, ByVal PolicyValue As UInt32)


end sub
```

what is wrong ?

Comment: Try it with SetPolicy(1, 3, a) and see if it gives an error.

Comment: Also try `SetPolicy(1, PipePolicyType.PIPE_TRANSFER_TIMEOUT, a)`

Comment: It would be nice if you would indicate that this is a Win32 function that you are p/invoking

Comment: actually is not calling anything (it's comment out to test) but I intend to call winusb_setpolicy(). Now originally imported works, but with const as folows: WinUsb_SetPipePolicy(hWinUSBInterface, ep, &H3, 4, timeout) and I try to replace arguments with some human readable consts

Comment: SetPolicy(1, 3, a) would give me: Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'SetPolicy' can be called without a narrowing conversion: ... there are two functions with PolicyValue as boolean or as uint32

Comment: Thanks a lot to all for attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call it using PipePolicyType.PIPE_TRANSFER_TIMEOUT

```
Public Class Form1
    Public Sub SetPolicy(ByVal ep As Integer, ByVal PolicyType As PipePolicyType, ByVal PolicyValue As UInt32)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim a As UInt32 = 3000

        SetPolicy(1, PipePolicyType.PIPE_TRANSFER_TIMEOUT, a)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Enum PipePolicyType
    SHORT_PACKET_TERMINATE = 1
    AUTO_CLEAR_STALL = 2
    PIPE_TRANSFER_TIMEOUT = 3
    IGNORE_SHORT_PACKETS = 4
    ALLOW_PARTIAL_READS = 5
    AUTO_FLUSH = 6
    RAW_IO = 7
    RESET_PIPE_ON_RESUME = 9
End Enum
```

Comment: I mark as good since it's perfect, thanks for effort. I found the problem totally somewhere else (see bellow)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found the problem totally somewhere else and I don't understand. There was no problem with my enums at all, some curious error in some wrapper to unmanaged:

```
    Dim PUnmanagedDetailedInterfaceDataStructure As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
    PUnmanagedDetailedInterfaceDataStructure = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(StructureSize)
```

This was shortened by me few days ago like this

```
    Dim PUnmanagedDetailedInterfaceDataStructure As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(StructureSize)
```

What is the problem with second declaration ?!